# How can I design input without knowing in advance how many values will be entered?

Tags: c

I want to input based on how many values a user inputs, without expecting an exact number of values.

In my program I want user to input integer(s) but the problem is that I want to allow the user to either input one or two space separated integers.

So,if user enters two space separated integers,they should get stored in variables a and b,and if he enters just one number before pressing enter then it should get stored in a,and the program should proceed further without waiting for the second number.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the whole input as a character array, than parse it as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you would do it yourself then turn that into code:

- Get a line from the input
- Tokenise it by whitespace
- Check that the tokens are integers can convert them

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do it easily with `scanf`:

```
int a,b;
char c[1];
int n = scanf("%d%0[ ]%d",&a,&c,&b);
```

It will read `b` only if it's separated by spaces, so it will stop at new-line.

`n` will contain number of fields read (including the separator).

I'm not sure if it's completely valid or cross-platform. You should check the documentation before putting it in any serious program.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the whole line as a character string using `fgets()` and then parse into the integer(s) you need.